# How to perform a many-to-many Linq query with Include in the EF

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I don't know how to perform this query using Linq and the EF.

Imagine I have three tables A, B and C.

A and B have a many-to-many relationship.
B and C have a 1-to-many relationship.

I want to obtain records from B including C but filtering from A's Id. I can get easily the records from B:

```
var result = Context.A.Where(x => x.Id.Equals(aId)).SelectMany(x => x.B);
```

but when I try to include C I don't know how to do it:

```
//This doesn't work    
var result = Context.A.Where(x => x.Id.Equals(aId)).SelectMany(x => x.B.Include("C"));
```

Also I've tried this with no luck (it is equivalent to the above):

```
//Not working
var result = (from a in Context.A.Where(x => x.Id.Equals(aId))
              from b in a.B.Include("C")
              select b);
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: check is there any null values in the id of context A . If there is any null values in the foreign key it will throw error .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I found the [Any](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534972.aspx) extension method...

This is the solution:

```
var result = (from b in Context.B.Include("C")
              where b.A.Any(x => x.A.Equals(aId))
              select b);
```